# Why does @user.update_attributes(nil) return true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, update-attributes

I'm writing a rails app and I'm trying to figure out why passing invalid params to update_attributes returns true.

valid params also return true.

For example:

```
@user.update_attributes(params[:user])
=> true
```

and

```
@user.update_attributes(params[:whatever])
=> true
```

Also

```
@user.update_attributes(false)
=> true

@user.update_attributes(nil)
=> true
```

Everything returns true. Why? And how do I check if valid params in update_attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update_attributes` will update the attributes passed, and if no attributes are passed then there's nothing to update and the record may be successfully saved.

`update_attributes` will return false if the record could not be saved due to validation. However, that doesn't mean the attributes in the hash are in error... it may be a field set elsewhere that made the record invalid.

```
# record has validation that email address must be valid format
@user.email = "invalid address"
@user.update_attributes(name: "Fred")
=> false # due to email error

# record has validation that email address must be valid format
@user.email = "fred@sample.com"
@user.update_attributes(name: "Fred")
=> true
```

`update_attributes` will raise an exception if you try to update an unknown attribute

```
@user.update_attributes(vegetable: "carrot")
#> ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: vegetable
```

Answer (score 1):

#update_attributes will first check if your model instance is #valid? before continuing on to write to the database. If your model instance is not #valid?, then it will return false. To see what's wrong with your model instance, take a look at your model's #errors.

if you have a validation that `first_name` can not be blank. Then it will return false:

```
@user.update_attributes(first_name: nil)
=> false

@user.errors.first
=> [:first_name, "can't be blank"]
```

For deep understanding the Source code
 # File activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb, line 2665

```
  def update_attributes(attributes)
    self.attributes = attributes
    save
  end
```

`true` or `false` is returned from the `save` method. So you will get `false` in case of invalid object. And `ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error` in case of mass-assignment exception.

Note that `Unknown Attributes` are considered as mass-assignment exception.

Comment: So update_attributes will return true regardless if what it's passed is valid, as long as you don't try to do something that isn't valid on the model?